# Marvel now! (Reboot) canon

Tags: marvel, comics, canon, continuity

Is marvel rebooting (again) after civil war 2 and going back to the name marvel now? If so will all the old marvel now titles be in continuity?
Thanks!

Comment: Everything is "canon"...just warped by cosmic interdimensional time-distorted magical events...or something.

Comment: Joe Quesada: [It's not a reboot](http://marvel.com/news/comics/19008/marvel_now)

Answer (score 2):

### It's not a reboot.

Editor in Chief, Alex Alonso, and Chief Creative Officer, Joe Quesada explained this [in an interview](http://marvel.com/news/comics/19008/marvel_now).

> Joe Quesada: Marvel NOW! is the next step in Marvel story evolution and character evolution. **It’s not a reboot.** It is a universe-shifting catch-all, which really just tells fans that if you enjoyed Avengers vs. X-Men, get ready for what the outcome is because there’s some major, major changes coming to the Marvel Universe. A lot of changes to the character status quos, alter egos, costumes, creator shifts, design shifts, the way that we do our covers, digital shifts and the way we start delivering our books.
>
> Joe Quesada: **A lot of characters and a lot of their stories are starting story arcs and different status quos right around this time.** I know there are a lot of people out there who are lapsed readers, or future readers who don’t necessarily know exactly how to jump into comics because the idea of decades and decades of continuity is daunting to them. Now mind you, they should never have that fear regardless, but for us we’re putting a flag in the sand and saying “Listen, if you’ve had that problem before, just take a flier on us. Try Marvel NOW!, **because we are not wiping the slate clean—we’re just trying to tell these stories from a clean point of view and allowing a good jumping-off point for new readers.”**

Even after this, the interviewer still asked if it was a reboot. Alonso, again, said it is not, and that it does not involve alt-universes.

> Marvel.com: Is this a reboot of the existing Marvel Universe?
>
> Axel Alonso: **It is not a reboot. We don’t travel back in time, into the future, or to an alternate universe.** Marvel NOW! respects the investment—emotional and financial—that long-term fans have made in the Marvel Universe, and this story takes place in a Marvel Universe they can recognize, one that grows out of Avengers Vs. X-Men. That said, these stories will be accessible to lapsed readers—the guy who likes, say, Captain America, but doesn’t know where to start—and anyone who saw a Marvel movie or heard the buzz about Marvel NOW!

### So what is it?

Marvel Now! is more about putting all the characters into accessible points for new readers to come on board. No history is being wiped clean by Marvel Now!.

That said, in the past few years, some universes were destroyed/merged as a part of Secret Wars.

Comment: So basically, it's a reboot.

Comment: If a reboot doesn't throw away anything or retcon anything, then yes. But since, Marvel Now doesn't, then no.

Comment: Sounds like a reboot to me. Anything that retroactively changes the origin story of a character ain't a "continuation".

Comment: except it *doesn't* retroactively change the origin story of anyone. it's pushing plotlines to easily accessible points for new readers.

Comment: But whatever. If you think it's a reboot, take it up with Quesada and Alonso.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a reboot, for civil war II they are using it as a way to show the different factions that form from the aftermath of civil war II. No plotlines or origin's will become uncannon

Comment: This doesn't appear to add anything to the existing answer.

Comment: The other answer is talking about the Now! branding that occurred after Avengers vs X-Men, the question was talking about the Now! branding occurring in October after Civil War II